# UIButton Blinking is working but, the button Action not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Using "@IBOutlet var checkAvalibilityBtn: UIButton!", created a blinking code and called in viewdidLoad

```
   `override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.checkAvalibilityBtn.alpha = 1.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.80, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
        self.checkAvalibilityBtn.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
    })`
```

But the buttion Action is not Working

`@IBAction func checkBAvaBtnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Success")
    }`

Comment: I think you need to invert your alpha there after it  works

Comment: If your button has alpha = 0.0, it won't catch the action

Comment: yes its working... Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

view alpha 0 does not receive touch events from the system, Refer SO old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146947/what-is-the-impact-of-view-alpha-0-vs-view-hidden-yes)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.checkAvalibilityBtn.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.80, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn, .repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
        self.checkAvalibilityBtn.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
    })
```