# Is viewcontroller's view's background color determine the size of the view or the tappable area of the view?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a code below that display red "Hello World!" in the middle of the cyan color view.
Clicking anywhere in the .cyan color, and in the red "Hello World!", will trigger an alert.

However, if I remove the `view.backgroundColor = .cyan` code, the background is dark (black) now. Tapping on the dark side will NOT trigger alert. Only tapping on the red "Hello World!" will trigger the alert.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .cyan
        let textLabel = UILabel()
        textLabel.text = "Hello World!"
        textLabel.textAlignment = .center
        view.addSubview(textLabel)
        textLabel.backgroundColor = .red

        textLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            $0.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        }

        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showAlert)))
    }
```

[image]
Why is this behavior? Is the view shrink if we don't have `.backgroundColor` set? Or just un-tappable if without the `.backgroundColor` set?

**Update**

Try out further using the below, based on @hell0friend comment.

1. Using `view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)`, will also make it NOT tappable.
2. Using `view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.001)`, will make it tappable.
3. Using `view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0001)`, will make it NOT tappable.

Looks like when alpha value that is 0.001 or above, then it is tappable, but when it below 0.001, it is not tappable.

p/s: all this happen only to the rootView of the ViewController, but not on the childview (e.g. `textLabel`). For `textLabel`, if we set the gesture over it, regardless of the alpha level, as long as it has `textLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`, it is always tappable.

**Additional info**

I use Xcode 11.3.1. I tried both iOS Target Development 13.2 and 11.0. They behave the same.

Comment: Hello! Try this two examples. In first example label won't react.  ->  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U2TckqBnHnqOB2MHPXAhiOhubb4AjjHB/view   and 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MlC46A-SkwlTvMAvA0ZuoIru5MuPgJin/view

Comment: This article https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest mentioned about `This method ignores view objects that are hidden, that have disabled user interactions, or have an alpha level less than 0.01`. 10x bigger than my findings. But nonetheless still explain something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the background color is not black, but clear. Clear color has an alpha equal to zero, that's why tapping will not trigger alert.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621945-clearcolor

EDIT:
To hide a view visually, you can either set its hidden property to YES or change its alpha property to 0.0. A hidden view does not receive touch events from the system.
See [What is the impact of view.alpha = 0 vs view.hidden = YES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146947/what-is-the-impact-of-view-alpha-0-vs-view-hidden-yes)

Comment: Does that means if I set the color to an alpha color, then it will not be tappable?

Comment: Tested to make my `textLabel` clear, and it is still tappable, as long as it is set `textLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: This is correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146947/what-is-the-impact-of-view-alpha-0-vs-view-hidden-yes

Comment: Based on @hellOfirend comment, I try out further, seems like there are some truth in it. I update my findings in the Question area

Comment: I think this answer deserved the to be the correct one, as indeed there's some strange behavior of the alpha color causing it not tappable. Some hint here.. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest

Comment: Thanks @hellOfriend for perserving with your answer despite downvoted by don't know who twice. I upvote your answer in the beginning already. Hopes people don't just downvote unknowingly.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
view.backgroundcolor = .clear
```

may be it will help you or just show the whole code

Comment: That's almost the whole code. It's within a `viewcontroller`. The only thing one need to implement is `showAlert`. If you want, you could add `@objc func showAlert() { print("I am here") }` to the code above, then it is complete. (Also it is using `snapkit` library)

Comment: Setting to `.clear` essentially is the same. My question is not to get it to work, but wonder if I don't set `.backgroundColor` why is it not tappable.

Comment: I've tried the same but it works in my case .. here i've attached a screenshot -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-P735Va2qtHXaov5MTXRG7rlD4JREg9m/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried your example, and the issue still there. Are you tapping on the Hello World or the surrounding places? I'm referring to the surrounding places tap is not responding.

Comment: i click on surroundings as well as on label . and it is working
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lfXysaIYeRbzMJeKF66RTxtVQgsgUR_Z/view?usp=sharing check video

Comment: Hmm, the fact that the background is white, it is not really clear.. Try `view.background = .clear`?

Comment: yeah sure..i will share the link as well

Comment: I think the background is already set somewhere, where the color is white. So that's why it is working.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o_wK3yw7wk7hSzbujy29rs83S3Pm3aN-?usp=sharing <- project link 
.. no i have copied your code and paste thats it

Comment: I see. I'm using SnapKit... to not use SnapSkit, the equivalent of the above is
```
        textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            textLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])```
 In your code, you just need to add `textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` to get that effect.